# EasyOCR and other python libraries will not install on pycharm, or any other code IDE. Nothing works

Tags: python, error-handling, package, pycharm, easyocr

I try to install lets say easyOCR on pycharm. Nothing at all will work.

I have tried everything, I uninstalled python, pycharm and all related coding files. I have used pip install and pycharms way of installing libraries. I get this same error

```
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'

The conflict is caused by:
    easyocr 1.6.2 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.6.1 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.6.0 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.5.0 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.4.2 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.4.1 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.4 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.3.2 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.3.1 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.3.0.1 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.3 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.2.5.1 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.2.5 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.2.4 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.2.3 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.2.2 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.2.1 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.2 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.10 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.9 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.8 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.7 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.6 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.5 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.4 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.3 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.2 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.1 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.0 depends on torch

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict


ERROR: Cannot install easyocr==1.0, easyocr==1.1, easyocr==1.1.1, easyocr==1.1.10, easyocr==1.1.2, easyocr==1.1.3, easyocr==1.1.4, easyocr==1.1.5, easyocr==1.1.6, easyocr==1.1.7, easyocr==1.1.8, easyocr==1.1.9, easyocr==1.2, easyocr==1.2.1, easyocr==1.2.2, easyocr==1.2.3, easyocr==1.2.4, easyocr==1.2.5, easyocr==1.2.5.1, easyocr==1.3, easyocr==1.3.0.1, easyocr==1.3.1, easyocr==1.3.2, easyocr==1.4, easyocr==1.4.1, easyocr==1.4.2, easyocr==1.5.0, easyocr==1.6.0, easyocr==1.6.1 and easyocr==1.6.2 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

this is the error message I get for EasyOCR. Other things like opencv work fine, but EasyOCR, PaddleOCR, tesserocr, and Torch do not work. Tesseract works as installs properly, but is the wrong OCR for what I am trying to do.

Comment: If you are on Windows you have to install `torch` and `torchvision` first as the installation instructions at https://pypi.org/project/easyocr/ say.

Comment: I have tried to install torch, and torch vision. Both do not work. I have even gone onto my laptop and tested EasyOCR and it installs perfectly. So the problem is just on my computer

Comment: It seems like you have other packages with conflicting requirements. Create a python environment and install it there.

Comment: yes I have done this, within pycharm my IDE. Everything was created inside of a "venv environment" I uninstalled pycharm, and all other packages on my computer. It is still giving me this error.